# How to dispatch an event when a object is ready on Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-html, dart-async

I'm experimenting some WebGL in Dart and I had created a class that loads shaders from separate files and I would like to throw an event (function) when the object is ready, so I can continue my application knowing that my shaders are properly loaded. Do someone knows an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

One approach is to use a Future pattern to accomplish this:

```dart
Future<SomeType> initMyObject(){
   final c = new Completer();

   // Do my object init stuff
   // and when it is complete:
   c.complete(instanceOfSomeType);

   // Return the Future object to any subscribers.
   return c.future;
}
```

Then elsewhere you can get notified like so:

```dart
initMyObject().then((SomeType t){
   //executes when future completes
});
```